# Querying for related items in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

so i have a database structure like this (simplified to related items

```
{
 users: {
   userId: {
     relatedContracts: [list of contract ids]
   }
 },
 contracts: {
   contractId: {
     ...contractMetaData
   }
 }
}
```

Now say that I want to get the related contracts and display them on the users home page. From the user object, I can get a list of contract ids.

I can write a separate query for each contract like this:

```
database.ref("/contracts/").child(contratId1).once('value')
database.ref("/contracts/").child(contractId2).once('value')
```

But is there anyway to batch this request. Such that i provide a list of ids and it returns all the related contracts.

What is the proper way of handling relations in a Document-Driven Database like this. Seems like doing one database request per relation would not scale very well?

Answer (score 0):

There's no scalability problem here.  X document fetches using document IDs are always going to result in X node lookups, no matter if they are batched or not.  The client libraries pipeline the requests to the server, which is just as good as batching anyway (and also give you the opportunity to start dealing with documents before they're all fetched, which batching would not allow).

Comment: Okay so its not creating a separate HTTP request for each lookup? 

But also I decided to switch to using CloudFirestore. Since it has some basic query logic built in

Comment: No, that would be massively unscalable.  Everything is piplined over a single socket.